# Error when clicking on Payment Methods in Magneto

Tags: mysql, magento, payment

When clicking on Payment Methods on the Configuration page i get this error.

`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'photocha_magento64.sales_order_status' doesn't exist`,

query was:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `state_table`.`state`, `state_table`.`is_default` FROM `sales_order_status` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `sales_order_status_state` AS `state_table` ON main_table.status=state_table.status WHERE (state_table.state='new') ORDER BY `main_table`.`label` ASC
```

Trace:

```
#0 /home/photocharms/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/photocharms/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/photocharms/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/photocharms/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /home/photocharms/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /home/photocharms/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /home/photocharms/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(740): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /home/photocharms/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /home/photocharms/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(572): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /home/photocharms/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /home/photocharms/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Config.php(173): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
#11 /home/photocharms/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Order/Status.php(46): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Config->getStateStatuses('new')
#12 /home/photocharms/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(463): Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Order_Status->toOptionArray(false)
#13 /home/photocharms/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(229): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#14 /home/photocharms/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(164): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->_initGroup(Object(Varien_Data_Form), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#15 /home/photocharms/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm()
#16 /home/photocharms/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(107): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm()
#17 /home/photocharms/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
#18 /home/photocharms/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#19 /home/photocharms/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 /home/photocharms/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 /home/photocharms/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 /home/photocharms/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#23 {main}
I have only 250 tables, the last table being 'persistent_session'
```

I have reinstalled the database previously and still only get 250 tables, reinstalling is not ideal as we have imported customer data from another store. Ideally we would like to write the new tabes.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

If you have a working backup file, please restore the tables:

```
sales_order_status
sales_order_status_label
sales_order_status_state
```

If you don't have a backup fine, you can reinstall only the missing tables

Just create a simple extension with 1 setup file. Use the installer for the `sales_order` module (`Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup`):

https://gyazo.com/ac50353c9facfd1c1fff3f87b3e97428

Create an installation file for your extension: 
https://gyazo.com/7dde13062355e792b15b39731f5ae117

And copy the following code (this is the copy of the sales/order installer with some changes)

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Sales_Model_Entity_Setup */
$installer = $this;

$statusTable        = $installer->getTable('sales/order_status');
$statusStateTable   = $installer->getTable('sales/order_status_state');
$statusLabelTable   = $installer->getTable('sales/order_status_label');

$installer->run(" 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$statusTable}` (
  `status` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
");

$statuses = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/sales/order/statuses')->asArray();
$data = array();
foreach ($statuses as $code => $info) {
    $data[] = array(
        'status'    => $code,
        'label'     => $info['label']
    );
}

try {
    $installer->getConnection()->insertArray($statusTable, array('status', 'label'), $data);
} catch (Exception $e) {

}

$installer->run(" 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$statusStateTable}` (
  `status` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `is_default` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`status`,`state`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_ORDER_STATUS_STATE_STATUS` FOREIGN KEY (`status`)
    REFERENCES `{$statusTable}` (`status`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
");
$states     = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/sales/order/states')->asArray();
$data = array();
foreach ($states as $code => $info) {
    if (isset($info['statuses'])) {
        foreach ($info['statuses'] as $status => $statusInfo) {
            $data[] = array(
                'status'    => $status,
                'state'     => $code,
                'is_default'=> is_array($statusInfo) && isset($statusInfo['@']['default']) ? 1 : 0
            );
        }
    }
}

try {
    $installer->getConnection()->insertArray(
        $statusStateTable,
        array('status', 'state', 'is_default'),
        $data
    );
} catch (Exception $e) {

}

$installer->run(" 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$statusLabelTable}` (
  `status` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`status`,`store_id`),
  KEY `FK_SALES_ORDER_STATUS_LABEL_STORE` (`store_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_ORDER_STATUS_LABEL_STATUS` FOREIGN KEY (`status`)
    REFERENCES `{$statusTable}` (`status`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_ORDER_STATUS_LABEL_STORE` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`)
    REFERENCES `{$installer->getTable('core/store')}` (`store_id`)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
");
```

After implementing this, the missing tables should appear and get filled with the standard info.

Comment: Appreciate your comments, have never made an extension before, would you mind providing a bit more help as to how to do as you described.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that difficult, especially taking into account that you don't need the most of its functionality.

Create the folder app/code/local/MageWorx/Fix
and sub-folders: 
etc
Helper
sql

https://www.gyazo.com/cf571d50e90ce7cd5068f0f723de5103

In the etc folder create the file: config.xml

https://www.gyazo.com/f024cbea6ae596d30f1da4715229df3b

With the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageWorx_Fix>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </MageWorx_Fix>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <mageworx_fix>
                <class>MageWorx_Fix_Helper</class>
            </mageworx_fix>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <mageworx_fix_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>MageWorx_Fix</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </mageworx_fix_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

In the Helper folder create the Data.php file ( https://www.gyazo.com/e5a71e283c387887da4582f04f8bf546 ) with the following content:

```
<?php

class MageWorx_Fix_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

In the sql folder create the subfolder mageworx_fix_setup:

https://www.gyazo.com/bd013b1fb638db1d943441eec7252baf

Inside of this, create the install-1.0.0.php file ( https://www.gyazo.com/cea0e9c2feedf83e3157ffcb2a85aa3f ) with the contents from the original post (the code after the phrase "And copy the following code (this is the copy of the sales/order installer with some changes)"):

внутри нее создайте файл install-1.0.0.php ( https://www.gyazo.com/cea0e9c2feedf83e3157ffcb2a85aa3f ) с содержанием из оригинального поста (код после фразы "And copy the following code (this is the copy of the sales/order installer with some changes)"):

As a result, you should get the following structure:

https://www.gyazo.com/b85a58a0f207ed48a774ff502e15d9b6

The last step is - the extension announcement. Create the file  MageWorx_Fix.xml in the directory app/etc/modules/ with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageWorx_Fix>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MageWorx_Fix>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Next, open your admin panel, refresh cache. The extension will get installed in create tables. The error should go away. 
When done, you can delete it.

Comment: Thank you for the help, i have done as you said buti am still getting the same error.

I can see the package has been installed, but it would appear that the 'photocha_magento64.sales_order_status' is not there.

I have photocha_magento64.sales_order_status_state and photocha_magento64.sales_order_status_label though

I had to add <?php and ?> tags at the end of the php code otherwise i got more errors.

Do you have anymore ideas? Ive tried reinstalling multiple times but for some reason i always get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the installation file should start with `<?php`.

Next, you should make sure that the extension got installed correctly. If the corresponding record doesn't appear in the table core_resource, it means the the installation process failed for some reason.

Check if all the files are in place, especially the extension files in the app/etc/modules folder. If the tables that contain 'state' and 'label' are there, you can shortcut the installer code to:

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Sales_Model_Entity_Setup */
$installer = $this;

$statusTable        = $installer->getTable('sales/order_status');

$installer->run(" 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$statusTable}` (
  `status` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
");

$statuses = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/sales/order/statuses')->asArray();
$data = array();
foreach ($statuses as $code => $info) {
    $data[] = array(
        'status'    => $code,
        'label'     => $info['label']
    );
}

try {
    $installer->getConnection()->insertArray($statusTable, array('status', 'label'), $data);
} catch (Exception $e) {

}
```